# AVAudioPlayer intermittently wont play sound

Tags: ios, ipad, avaudioplayer

I have a music player app on ipad. I download m4a files from a server and save them to doc dir. I also use Core Data to save the playlist info. I have over 1000 songs and my table loads perfectly and plays perfectly. I can play the playlists thru with no problems. BUT... every once in a while one song does not play. NO SOUND! I can press the cell to play the song or goto the next song and everything works again. So this problem is random and intermittent. It's never the same song that gets stuck. I cant give you any debug statements, cus like I said, it's so random and intermittent that it's hard to duplicate. I'm wondering if it's an ARC problem. Please help, as this app is going to production very soon.

Relative code:

```
// setup music session
NSError *error = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setDelegate: self];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error: &error];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &error];

NSLog(@"error AVAudioSession:%@", [error description]);

AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] init];
NSString *fullPath = fullPath = [self.docDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
NSURL *musicFileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:fullPath];

// getting song from docDir
    NSData *songData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFileURL];
    player = [player initWithData:songData error:&error];
    NSLog(@"error player reg:%@", [error description]);

//NSLog(@"playing %@ at index:%d", musicFileURL, index);

    self.appPlayer = player;

    [self.appPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.appPlayer setEnableRate: YES];
    [self.appPlayer setDelegate: self];
    [self.appPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use ARC a good point to start to solve your problem is to watch the reference counting in Instruments. I had the problem as well. None of my files were playing. I've seen in Instruments that the AVAudioPlayer instance was released BEFORE the sound started to play. At least it looked like it was released. After i've stored the reference of AVAudioPlayer in the core data model the bug was fixed! In another project without ARC the same code did work without storing the reference.

Comment: Thank you for answering my Q after so long. Indeed my problem was related to releasing before it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

or you can try to use strong instead of retain in the property declaration

@property(nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;